# Removing reverse mapping enum keys on TSC compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, tsc

For some reason, when I compile a node module created using typescript, I get for each Enum a reverse mapping of it also.
I don't need it and can't remove it. is there a way to compile without getting it?

for example:

- ts file

```
export enum example {
 a = 1,
 b = 2
}
```

after compile:

- js file

```
var example;
(function (example) {
 bla[bla['a']=1]='a'
 bla[bla['b']=2]='b'
})(example = exports.example || (exports.example={}));
```

and when I import it I get:

```
enum example {
 a:1,
 b:2,
 1:a,
 2:b
}
```

which is not what I aimed to be using.

Haven't found anything about it anywhere. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [`const` enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums).

The compiled JavaScript file will have no mapping at all. All `enum` uses will be converted into their respective value.

```
const enum example {
 a = 1,
 b = 2
}

console.log(example.a)
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
console.log(1 /* example.a */);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgW3gDwIbIA4Bs4wDeAUDBjALwwCMANKQEaUwBMxAvscaJCPgHS4QAcwAUcTDgEYAlEA)

Comment: What's the difference between `const enum example { ... }` and `const example { ... }`? Is there any advantage over using the `const enum`?

Comment: The only advantage is that the compiled JavaScript file is smaller. But you are losing the mapping capabilities.

Comment: Im rather asking whats the difference between `const enum example` over `const example`? Does it makes any sense at all to do so?

Comment: One difference is that when you want to type a variable, you can use `const a: example` for the `enum` variant. But for the object, you would need to say `const: a example[keyof typeof example]`.

Comment: Huh. So I believe I will stay with enums. :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is it possible that enums behave differently in typescript than in javascript?

Comment: @ishaishai - enums don't exist in JavaScript. The TypeScript enums get compiled into these JavaScript object lookup tables like the one you have in your post.